# Flutter stream's snapshot has no data

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to make a flutter mobile app with my own back end using Django rest framework, and JWT

My flow is, after signing in i will store access token in local storage, and create a stream to update the widget (like `FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()`). It's working fine but after i switching screen, my stream has NO DATA, and it show login screen

Below is my creation of that stream (token_services.dart), while `localStorage` is from [localstorage package](https://pub.dev/packages/localstorage)

```
StreamController<String> accessTokenStreamController =
    StreamController<String>.broadcast();

Stream<String> get accessTokenStream => accessTokenStreamController.stream;

void setAccessToken(String accessToken) {
  localStorage.setItem('access_token', accessToken);
  accessTokenStreamController.add(accessToken);
}

String getAccessToken() {
  return localStorage.getItem('access_token');
}
```

Here is my screen (account_screen.dart):

```
class AccountScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AccountScreenState createState() => _AccountScreenState();
}

class _AccountScreenState extends State<AccountScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: accessTokenStream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null)
            return AuthorizedScreen();
          else
            return UnauthorizedScreen();
        });
  }
}
```

And the root screen:

```
class Wrapper extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _WrapperState createState() => _WrapperState();
}

class _WrapperState extends State<Wrapper> {
  int status = 0;

  List<Map> screens = [
    {'name': 'Home', 'widget': HomeScreen(), 'icon': Icon(Icons.home)},
    {
      'name': 'Account',
      'widget': AccountScreen(),
      'icon': Icon(Icons.account_circle)
    },
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(child: screens[status]['widget']),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        currentIndex: status,
        items: screens
            .map((scr) =>
                BottomNavigationBarItem(label: scr['name'], icon: scr['icon']))
            .toList(),
        onTap: (value) {
          setState(() {
            status = value;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note that if i provide `initialData` to `StreamBuilder`, it's completely fine